# Why my typereference not work?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Here is my code.

First, I have two classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractTypeReference<T> {
    public Type type();
    public AbstractTypeReference() {
        Type superClass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        type = ((ParameterizedType) superClass).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
}

public class MyTypeReference<T> extends AbstractTypeReference<T> {
    public MyTypeReference() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Then, I run following code:

```
MyTypeReference<String> ref = new MyTypeReference<String>();
System.out.println(ref.type.toString());
```

I expect to get `java.lang.String` as output, but get `T` instead.
The code was copied from `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type`. But it works well. Could anyone tell me what is wrong? And why?

Comment: You'd need to use `AbstractTypeReference<String> ref = new AbstractTypeReference<String>() {};` (or `public class MyTypeReference extends AbstractTypeReference<String>{...`). Otherwise, you lose the type information because of erasure. "The code was copied from " Please show where it was copied from.

Comment: @AndyTurner Sorry I lose the class. It's from `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference`.